# Removing a Parent Theme's Menu Items

Tags: parent-theme

I have a parent theme that is using this code to create menus:

```
function cornerstone_menus() {

    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'header-menu-left' => __( 'Header Menu (left)', 'cornerstone' ),
            'header-menu-right' => __( 'Header Menu (right)', 'cornerstone' ),
            'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu', 'cornerstone' )
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'cornerstone_menus' );
```

In my child theme, I want my own menus, so I've created them, but these three parent theme menu items still show up in the Appearance > Menu section. I have a function in my child theme that removes the menus:

```
function remove_cornerstone_menus() {
    unregister_nav_menu( 'header-menu-left' );
    unregister_nav_menu( 'header-menu-right' );
    unregister_nav_menu( 'footer-menu' );
}
```

but I don't know what action to tie it to in order for it to work.  I assumed that since the menu creation is being called in the "init" action, I could do this:

```
add_action('init', 'remove_cornerstone_menus');
```

But the menus still show up. I read elsewhere that I needed to hook into the after_setup_theme action, so I tried this:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_cornerstone_menus');
```

But that didn't work either.  I'm at a loss as to how to remove the menus. I can manually remove them, but if the theme updates I'll have to do it again, and I'm trying to avoid that, which is why I'm using a child theme.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course right after I post this, I find an answer...so hopefully someone else can benefit from this.  For me, the answer was instead of unregistering nav menu items, I needed to just remove the action...so my function now looks like this:

```
function remove_cornerstone_menus() {
    remove_action('init', 'cornerstone_menus');
}

add_action('init', 'remove_cornerstone_menus');
```

Worked like a charm.