# Hook in parent theme Menu function

Tags: theme-development, filters, child-theme

Trying to modify Parent Menus function on child theme, the original function is:

```
function original_theme_menus() {
    $menus = array(
        'top'       => __( 'Top Menu', 'theme-domain' ),
        'primary'   => __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme-domain' ),
        'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'theme-domain' ),    
    );
    return apply_filters( 'original_theme_menus', $menus );
}
```

I'm doing:

```
function remove_original_theme_menus() {
    remove_action('original_theme_menus');
}
add_action('init', 'remove_original_theme_menus');

    function original_theme_menus() {
        $menus = array(
            'top'       => __( 'Top Menu', 'theme-domain' ),
            'primary'   => __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme-domain' ),
            'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'theme-domain' ),
            'footer'    => __( 'Footer Menu', 'theme-domain' )

        );
        return apply_filters( 'original_theme_menus', $menus );
    }
```

**How should I unregister the original function?**

I get a Fatal Error because the original function is still there and cannot redeclare it.

I tried creating a new function name but the problem is the original one; If I just remove the original parent function everything works as expected.

I've read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133602/adding-action-hooks-in-parent-theme-for-easier-child-theme-customization) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113513/removing-a-parent-themes-menu-items) to solve on my own but can not figure out what is the proper way to unregister~override the original menu function, and call it  from child theme functions.

I presume it is also related with the "init" part because I should be doing this on the apply filters instead.

Comment: I tried changing **init** with **after_setup_theme**, an also different priorities, with no luck.

Comment: Please just wait two days until you mark the answer as solution. The same goes for answering your own question (which you can do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to fire the original one, not to remove.

```
add_filter( 'original_theme_menus', 'your_theme_menus', 1, 1 );
function your_theme_menus( $menus )
{
    $new_menu = array(
        'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu', 'theme-domain' )
    );
    $menus = $menus + $new_menu;

    return $menus;
}
```